# How can I use a parameter in place of a property in an Angular component?

Tags: angular

```
editTopic(category) {
  this.topicForm.controls.category.disable();
}
```

How can I use the parameter `category` as a variable to dynamically disable different formGroups inside of my form using the above section in my component.ts? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is your logic not working?

Comment: this code is giving me the console error 'Cannot read property 'disable' of undefined'
however if I pass 'category' to my console.log, it's the expected value

Comment: if i do a manual fix by specifying if (category == 'expectedValue') and then the same logic inside, with category replaced by expectedValue it works as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the solution is simple ;-)

You just need to adjust the control access and access the control via the bracket notation, like following:

```
editTopic(category) {
  this.topicForm.controls[category].disable();
}
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) for more information about this kind of property access ;-)